# Getting urls with csv reader and putting them into a list

Tags: python, csv, reader

Im trying to make a very simple program where I have two csv files with lists of domains or blog post urls in them. Im trying to import the first one and make the column of domains and column of prices into a dictionary which I have managed to do.

Now I want to import the second csv file which is just a single column of blog post urls.

After I import the urls from the second file and print them out every url seems to be wrapped in [] within a list like so:

[['http://www.gardening-blog.com/post-1'],['http://www.foodie-blog.com/post-2'],['http://www.someotherblog.com/post-1'].... etc etc

is this something to do with importing with csv reader?

Also I have another question, what is the best way to strip the 'http://' and 'www.' from the list of urls? I have 2 ways Ive tried below using map and join (commented out) but they wont work, I have a feeling thats to do with the list problem though. I have done this with the dictionary but I can't use replace with a list.

thanks

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("domains_prices.csv", 'r'))

reader2 = csv.reader(open('orders_list.csv', 'r'))

domains_prices={}

orders_list = list(reader2) #import all blog post urls into a list


for domain, price in reader:
    domain = domain.replace('http://', '').replace('www', '')
    domains_prices[domain] = price

#orders_list = ''.join(orders_list).replace('http://','').split()

#map(str.strip, orders_list)

print orders_list
```

EDIT

here's what Ive changed and seems to work now:

```
orders_list = []


for row in reader2:
    orders_list.append(','.join(row))

orders_list = [s.replace('http://', '').replace('www.','') for s in    orders_list]
```

Comment: ok I think I may have figured it out by doing the following:                            for row in reader2:
 orders_list.append(','.join(row))                                                                  that seems to have created a list, although I still dont understand why those square brackets were put around each item the first time I tried to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically `csv.reader` reads custom csv file, and his next() method gives next row, and in python this row is represented as list, even if it consists of a single field. That is why you are receiving list of lists with single element, instead of implicit reading like `list(reader2)` probably you want to it explicitly:

```
orders_list = [row[0] for row in reader2]
```

And as you want to remove "http://" and "www" from urls you can do it right inside that construction:

```
orders_list = [row[0].replace("http://", "").replace("www.", "") for row in reader2]
```

But I would suggest to be more smart with removing of http's and www, as schema might be either "http" or "https", and I guess you want to remove only "www" from the start of link. So you can take a look at urllib2.urlparse module, and also check net location (link) if it starts with "www":

```
url = url.replace("www.", "", 1) if url.startswith("www.") else url
```

Note: 1 stands in `url.replace("www.", "", 1)` to avoid removing "www" from inside of url address, for example if you have something like this: "www.facebook.com/best-www-address".

And yes finally you can come to something like this:

```
links = []
for row in reader2:
    edited_link = row[0].replace("http://", "", 1) if row[0].startswith("http://") else row[0]
    edited_link = edited_link.replace("https://", "", 1) if edited_link.startswith("https://") else edited_link
    edited_link = edited_link.replace("www.", "", 1) if edited_link.startswith("www.") else edited_link
    links.append(edited_link)
```

Comment: thanks, I figured it out I think and made some edits to my code in the post above